# How to session check in only interceptor for spring boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have some controller for user update, article update, delete etc..

I don't want to check a session in controller, When a user tries to update a article, the user only can update his own article.

So, I tried to handle this action in interceptor but this approach couples interceptor with controller.

Currently, I'm checking the user action as the following...

```
String param = request.getParameter("id");

// A user accesses his own resource.
((String)session.getAttribute("key")).eqauls(param) == true
```

But, when request parameter doesn't uses directly a `id`,
i have to add some statement like following...

```
String param2 = request.getParameter("email");
// here, i have to add some logic to find the id using email.
....
```

Comment: Why not use Spring Security?

Comment: I haven't learned Spring Security yet.